# Changing Dataframe Column name without changing Type

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (`df`) in which I rename one of columns using:

```
print('Type Before',type(df))

df= df.rename(columns={df.columns[14]: "Total requests" }, inplace = True)

print('Type after',type(df))
```

If I check the `type` before and after the the column name change the dataframe changes from a `DataFrame` to `NoneType`

```
Type Before <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Type after<class 'NoneType'>
```

Is there a way to change the name of a column using the column number while keeping the type as a Dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If use `inplace=True` it return `None`.

So need remove `inplace=True` and assign back:

```
df= df.rename(columns={df.columns[14]: "Total requests" })
```

Or is possible remove `inplace`, but I think `inplace` is not good practice, check [this](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace) and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529):

```
df.rename(columns={df.columns[14]: "Total requests" }, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Jezrael explained the issue behind you receiving `None` so I have nothing to add there. I'll provide very similar approach, just using less letters with `list` instead of `columns`:

```
df = df.rename(columns={list(df)[14]:"Total requests"})
```